# Medir caracteres en Bash

Tags: bash, shell-script

Tengo que medir la longitud de los caracteres de 1 o más argumentos introducidos por la terminal, si la suma de los caracteres es mayor que 80, entonces decir cuantas columnas ocupa.

Esto es lo que he intentado, pero no acaba de funcionar completamente:

```
#!/bin/bash

clear

if test $# -lt 1; then
echo No has indicado uno o más argumentos
exit 3
fi

len= echo $(expr length $#)
echo "La longitud de caracteres de los parámetros pasados es de: $len"

if [ $len -lt "80" ];
then
echo "El número de filas ocupado por los parámetros introducidos es 1"
else
echo "El número de filas ocupado por los parámetros introducidos es mayor "
fi
```

Comment: Qué tal? Podrías poner un ejemplo de que entrada esperas recibir y qué salida?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Espero haber entendido bien tu problema, en tal caso el código que lo resuelve sería:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

clear

amount_args=$#
if test $amount_args -lt 1; then
  echo "No has indicado uno o más argumentos"
  exit 3
fi

all_args=$*
len=${#all_args}

# Le quito los espacios entre los argumentos de entrada
let "len = len - amount_args + 1"

echo "La suma de la longitud de caracteres de los argumentos pasados es de: $len"

if [ $len -lt "80" ];
then
  echo "El número de filas ocupado por los argumentos introducidos es 1"
else
  (($len % 80)) && let "rows = (len / 80) + 1" || let "rows = (len / 80)"
  echo "El número de filas ocupado por los argumentos introducidos es: $rows"
fi
```

Ojala te sirva, saludos :)